# Stream stream joins without equality predicate is not supported

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am using Spark 2.3 and am trying to join two streams of data. My left and my right stream both have an array. I want to join the two streams only when the right stream array is a subset of the left stream array.

For instance, my streamA looks like this:

```
StreamA:
|---|------|---------------------|-----------|
|id | dept | employeesInMeetings | DateTime  |
|---|------|---------------------|-----------|
| 1 | sales| [John]              | 7/2 14:00 |
| 2 | mktg | [Adam, Mike]        | 7/2 12:30 |
| 3 | hr   | [Rick, Jill, Andy]  | 7/2 14:00 |
|---|------|---------------------|-----------|
```

and my streamB looks as follows:

```
StreamB:
|--------------|--------------|----------|
|employees     | confRooms    | DateTime |
|--------------|--------------|----------|
| [John, Jane] |      A       | 7/2 14:00|
| [Adam, Mike] |      C       | 7/2 12:30| 
| [Jill, Andy] |      B       | 7/2 14:00|
|--------------|--------------|----------|
```

I only care about employees from the same department that are in the same meeting. Hence, as a result of the intersection, my resulting stream needs to look like:

```
|---|------|---------------------|-----------|----------|
|id | dept | employeesInMeetings | DateTime  | confRoom |
|---|------|---------------------|-----------|----------|
| 2 | mktg | [Adam, Mike]        | 7/2 12:30 |    C     |
| 3 | hr   | [Rick, Jill, Andy]  | 7/2 14:00 |    B     |
|---|------|---------------------|-----------|----------|
```

I created a UDF to do the intersect:

```
val arrayIntersect = udf((leftArr: Array[String], rightArr: Array[String]) => {
  import spark.implicits._
  if(leftArr.intersect(rightArr.toSeq).length == rightArr.size){
    true
  } else {
    false
  }
})
```

And tried to use it as follows:

```
streamA.joinWith(streamB, expr("arrayIntersect(leftArr, rightArr) AND streamA.DateTime BETWEEN streamB.DateTime and streamB.DateTime + INTERVAL 12 hours"))
```

However, I get the error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Stream stream joins without equality predicate is not supported;
```

Does anybody know if there is a workaround here? Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no workaround for this in stream-stream joins :(

We really need an equality predicate because we use that to perform the join using a streaming symmetric hash join algorithm -- both the streams are partitioned using the common key so that the related records from both streams end up in the same partition.

Comment: Thanks! Are there plans of incorporating non equality predicates in Stream-stream joins?

Answer (score -1):

First convert your array into string and then search you right Array String in left Array String.

```
val arrayToString = udf{arr: Seq[String] => arr.sorted.map(_.trim.toLowerCase).mkString(",")}

streamA.withColumn("leftArrStr", arrayToString(col("leftArr"))).joinWith(
  streamB.withColumn("rightArrStr", arrayToString(col("rightArr")))
  , expr("instr(leftArrStr, rightArrStr) != 0 " +
    "AND streamA.DateTime BETWEEN streamB.DateTime and streamB.DateTime + INTERVAL 12 hours"))
```

Comment: Hello @Kaushal, doing a string comparison might produce incorrect results. For instance, if my left array (sorted) is `[Andy, Jade, Jill, Rick] and my right array (sorted) is [Andy, Rick], the join condition will fail, wouldn't it? Thoughts?

Comment: I just tried to implement the solution you suggested and I still received the same error. Did you test your solution?

Comment: @DataGeek Values of DateTime column is in sync? if it is then explode your arrays and then join individual employees also with DateTime condition, because same person can not be in two or more places.

Comment: Thanks @Kaushal - That's the approach I'm taking now. Will update the post once I have a resolution.